# Facebook Open Share Window from Application

Tags: facebook

How can I open the Share with friends window from inside a Flash application please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a window to `http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u={URL}` where `{URL}` the the urlencoded URL of the page you want to share.

Comment: Thank you, daaku! Will this open a new browser window or will it open the Facebook popup which is a floating DIV?

Comment: Hm, that's nice, but what I wanted was a way of opening the Popup window that enables you to share with friends by typing in their names and all that.

Comment: The user can click the "Send as Message" link on the bottom left. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Hm sorry for being so unclear, what I mean is the Invite Friends internal PopUp window, where you can select friends and send them an e-mail, like in this screenshot: http://67.23.226.27/~francisc/invite.jpg